# Some mythological riddling

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> Some Might Call Me Thought,
>
> Where Others Call Me The Intellectual Capability.
>
> I Soar Trough The Air Each Morning With My Duplicate,
>
> Seeing All And Hearing All.
>
> Who Might I Be?

Comment: something like soul ?

Comment: you got to think a bit in synonyms with the first 2 sentences

Comment: Yes, but it's not fit for 3rd line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be

> Huginn or possibly Muninn

Some mythological riddling

> H and M are Odin's raven companions in Norse mythology

Some Might Call Me Thought,

Where Others Call Me The Intellectual Capability.

> According to Wikipedia, Huginn means "Thought" and Muninn means "Memory" or "Mind"

I Soar Trough The Air Each Morning With My Duplicate,

> The ravens flew throughout the world

Seeing All And Hearing All.

> The ravens gathered information for Odin

Comment: can't argue. spot on. it's Huginn